# Sendmsg(UDP) with ancillary message to set source port

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a UDP socket on which i have specified the **IP_PKTINFO** flag
to pass a ancillary message containing a pktinfo struct to set a custom source address

```
struct in_pktinfo {
  unsigned int   ipi_ifindex;
  struct in_addr ipi_spec_dst;
   struct in_addr ipi_addr;
};
```

**struct in_addr** is just wrapping struct around a unsigned long

```
struct in_addr {
   unsigned long s_addr;  // load with inet_aton()
};
```

On my implementation:

Datagrams arriving on a transparent UDP socket(tproxy), analyzed, processed
and then forwarded to a specific destination(Port Address Translation).
So it is crucial for me to set the source IP as well as source port.

I can realize setting a specific source port if i open new socket and bind to it,
because of the large amount of datagrams it is very inefficient.

Questions:
is there anyway to set the source port without multiple sockets/binds or using a raw socket.

Comment: What have you tried? It says you can pass an IP_PKTINFO to sendmsg.

Comment: yes, i can set any source ip but no port if i set pktinfo->ipi_spec_dst. i can also do it like this using a SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP on a transparent socket(IP_TRANSPARENT) setting the UDP header(e.g. src/dst port) by hand  and then using pktinfo to set the src ip so this way i don't need to set the whole ip header. so i wonder if there is anything like in pktinfo to affect the UDP header.